# Does concat use the same memory as push to modify a local array

Tags: javascript, arrays, memory-management

I usually concat different arrays in this way. The code works well.

```
var input = {a: [1,2,3,4,5], b: [2,3,4,5,6]}
var result = []
Object.keys(input).forEach(k => {
  var value = input[k]
  result = result.concat(value)
})
```

I don't know, how JS manages reference counting. From my naive understanding, `concat()` will allocate a new memory block, copy existing array content of `result` and then fill the address afterwards with the content of `value`. If this makes sense, there will be a lot of memory copy operations, if the `input` variable has a lot of keys and values. (My actual `input` data on disk can be 3-5MB)

Now I'm thinking whether I should use `push()` instead to reduce memory copy in this case.

```
var input = {a: [1,2,3,4,5], b: [2,3,4,5,6]}
var result = []
Object.keys(input).forEach(k => {
  var value = input[k]
  value.forEach(v => {
    result.push(v)
  })
})
```

I think, `push()` will only do array resize, if its capacity cannot hold all contents. The only reason I did not use `push()` at the first place is code readability.

**Which variant will consume less memory?**

Comment: Under the hood, Concat will also do the pushy thing. I sense no difference.

Comment: Note that a large amount of pushes are likely to have more performance overhead. Reason is that it will go (vaguely) push -> push -> resize -> GC -> push -> push -> resize -> GC -> push -> push etc. Not _precisely_ that, of course but resizing takes some time and doing a large number of pushes to an array will involve multiple resizes. Allocating an array of a big enough size first then adding should take more memory but be of consistent speed. Not sure what `.concat` will do but I'd expect it to be at least _as_ performant as multiple .`push`-es, but likely more.